# Use MacBook charger for Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: power, power-supply, pi-4

I am using the official 15.3W USB-C Power Supply to power up my Raspberry Pi 4.

I got my self a second Raspberry Pi 4 but I haven't bought the power supply yet. 
 Would I be able to use the Macbook Pro 87W USB-C Power Adapter
 instead?

I know that some devices only ask for so much current, and the adapter will not give more than that. Not sure if that's the case with RPi 4.

Comment: Simple answer - try it. You shouldn't do any harm as long as it works to the USB-C spec. Worst case is it won't boot.

Comment: Yes, Rpi won't ask more current than it needs.  But I heard that Rpi4 does not like Apple's USB-C charger.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

NOTE: Please read the `Follow up, 14 Aug 2020` near the end of this post. The *"Raspberry Organization"* has released revised hardware for the RPi 4B that you should know about before buying.

### Revised Answer:

**It will not damage your RPi, but it won't work unless you use a `NON e-marked` USB-C cable** (*details follow*).

The Macbook Pro 87W USB-C Power Adapter has enough power to run the RPi 4B. The specifications printed on the adapter state that its 5.2 volt output is rated at 2.4 Amps.

***HOWEVER...***, it seems that the Raspberry Pi designers didn't read the USB-C specs, and didn't test their design very well before releasing it to production. This has been reported in several sources, including [this post on TechRepublic](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/your-new-raspberry-pi-4-wont-power-on-usb-c-cable-problem-now-officially-confirmed/), [this post on Hackaday](https://hackaday.com/2019/07/16/exploring-the-raspberry-pi-4-usb-c-issue-in-depth/), and further analyzed in [this post by Tyler Ward](https://www.scorpia.co.uk/2019/06/28/pi4-not-working-with-some-chargers-or-why-you-need-two-cc-resistors/). Or perhaps, The Foundation simply wanted to sell more of [their "official" power supplies](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/type-c-power-supply/) for the RPi 4B?

And so despite the fact that the Macbook Pro 87W USB-C Power Adapter ([now replaced by the 96W supply](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MX0J2AM/A/96w-usb-c-power-adapter)) has more than ample power to handle the RPi 4, the RPi 4 is missing hardware that allows it to work with `e-marked` USB-C cables. A design that is compliant with the USB-C specifications will work with `e-marked` USB-C cables ([more info](https://www.elinfor.com/market/how-to-identify-the-usb-c-cables-with-or-without-e-maker-m-27)); unfortunately, the Raspberry Pi 4 will not.

The reasons for this [bodge](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=bodge) are less important now than the remedies, so let's get on with that.

The (most practical) solutions are:

1. Buy the ["Official" power supply sold by the Raspberry Organization](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/type-c-power-supply/), or
2. Get a `NON e-marked` USB-C cable.

I saw no reason to cause the manufacture of yet another "wall wart" that may eventually wind up in a landfill when I've already got enough USB-C cables and chargers. It's a **standard** - right? And so I didn't buy the "official" power supply when I bought my RPi 4. For me personally, Option 1. is a "no-go" at this point.

For Option 2, [Tom's Hardware has conveniently provided a list of USB-C cables they've tested](https://www.tomshardware.com/news/raspberry-pi-4-usb-c-cables-that-work,39869.html) that they claim will work with the RPi 4. Tom's also expressed understanding and compassion for the Raspberry Pi organization. I don't buy it, but to each his own.

I've not tried a different cable yet, but when I do, I'll follow up here with the results. In the meantime, I did try my Macbook Pro USB-C charging cable and 87W power supply. I confirmed that it **DOES NOT** power up the RPi 4. Also note that after trying my Macbook cable & charger on the RPi 4, *I had to unplug and re-plug my power supply before it would charge my Macbook again!* Just for grins, I also tried a new-ish USB-C charger made by Apple for an iPhone (18 watts as I read the low-contrast specs printed on the charger) with the same result: the 18 watt charger with Apple charging cable **DOES NOT** power up the RPi 4.

### Follow up, 26 Dec 2019:

I obtained an [*el-cheapo*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/el%20cheapo) USB-C charging cable (aka `NON e-marked` cable) [from Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01GGKZ2SC). I tried this cable with my Macbook Pro 87W USB-C Power Adapter. This combination successfully powered the RPi 4B. I also tried this same cable with [Apple's 18 watt iPhone charger](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MU7T2LL/A/18w-usb-c-power-adapter). This combination also successfully powered the RPi 4B, and has continued to do so for more than 24 hours as of this writing.

### Follow up, 14 Aug 2020:

Here's how to tell which version of the RPi4 you have ([REF](https://tutorial.cytron.io/2020/02/22/how-to-check-if-your-raspberry-pi-4-model-b-is-rev1-2/)):

```
$ cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep Revision
```

If the result is :

- `Revision : b03111` It's an ORIGINAL RPi4 with USB-C design flaw, and a `NON e-marked` cable is required for use with a USB-C charger.
- `Revision : c03112` It's a newer RPi4 with the corrective fix; you may use ***any*** cable - either an `e-marked` cable, or a `NON e-marked` cable.

Comment: Thanks! So if I got it correctly, it should work as long as I switch to the `NON e-marked` USB-C cable? The power adapter may remain the one from MacBook

Comment: @Dino: Yes, the power supply itself is not the issue; it's the cable (see the `Follow up` section above). TL;DR the USB-C spec, but it ***appears*** that the cable is used to signal the power supply what output voltage to suppy. E.g. when you're charging your Macbook, the PS outputs 20 VDC; when it's powering a 5 V (USB2) device, the PS outputs 5 VDC. Non `e-marked` cables will only allow 5 VDC.

Answer (score 0):

If you put an adapter (like the uni HDMI adapter with an additional USB-C line) in-between it will work too. If you have a MacBook Pro you'll have one for sure.