# Power Pi4 with USB-C Power Bank

Tags: power-supply, pi-4, battery, alternative-power, usb-c

Can a USB-C Power Bank be used to power a Pi 4 for off-grid or mobile uses where the Pi cannot be tethered to either a mains electric socket or a POE switch?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Intro:

Many of my contributions to this forum have centered around innovative ways to power a Pi which is awkwardly out of reach of a mains socket, specifically using POE.  ***But what do you do if there's no mains power source at all***, ie: Pi used in off-grid conditions or mobile use where the Pi is not stationary?

As the Pi 4 now had a USB-C Power socket, I thought it would be useful to revisit using a USB Power Bank as a power source which although worked with earlier Pi models threw under-voltage warnings.

### Short Answer:

Yes, USB-C Power Banks **CAN** be used to power a Pi 4 without triggering an under-voltage alert, but with following notes:

- **USB Power Banks**: Can vary widely in quality, affecting results
- **Cables Used**: Using long, thin-gauge cables reduce voltage supplied to Pi
- **Pi Applications**: Test Pi in use-case configuration to determine how much power it will consume for required period it must remain powered. For example, video encoding for a security camera will burn through power a lot faster than just running an SSH server on the same Pi.
- **Under-Voltage**: Despite only a single "*Under-Voltage*" warning seen during testing, neither USB Power Bank tested achieved a full 5v (*but came **very** close*).  Although electrical equipment can be damaged by **OVER**-voltage conditions, it's also possible (however *much less likely*) that [damage *could* result to hardware from **UNDER**-voltage conditions](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/65824/can-electronics-be-damaged-by-undervolting-it). Given the negligible cost of a Pi, I'm not terribly concerned

If interested in ***HOW*** my conclusions reached, please continue reading...

### Testing Objectives:

- Determine relative power performance of different USB-C Power Banks & cables combinations to power a Pi 4
- Identify combinations which resulted in Pi throwing an under-voltage warning ("*Lightning Bolt*" displayed in top upper-right screen corner)
- Record sufficient detail to enable independent verification of results

### Testing: How Power Measured

- Wait until Pi fully booted
- Take pics over a period of a minute to identify high-low voltage & amperage ranges. Not totally precise, but good enough

**NOTE**: Only (1) snap for each high & low value for each test will be shown

### Test Equipment

Equipment used in tests was employed because I had it in my office at hand. There may be better or worse Power Banks & USB-C cables then those used in my tests.

- **Pi 4**: Configured w/ cooling fan- which itself has additional power draw- as a wireless AP with "[pi-ap](https://github.com/f1linux/pi-ap)"
- **Official Pi USB-C Mains power cable**
- **USB-C Power Tester**: Satechi USB-C Power Meter Tester Multimeter
- **USB Power Bank #1**: 20100 mAh Zendure X6 USB-C Hub and Power Bank with 20100mAh
- **USB Power Bank #2**: 20100 mAh Reka Power Bank (Aldi's supermarket £29.99)
- **USB-C Cable #1**: 21" Cable packaged w/ ***Zendure*** Power Bank
- **USB-C Cable #2**: 40" Cable packaged w/ ***Reka*** Power Bank

**NOTE**: Both USB-C cables were end-to-end USB-C with no adapters used between the Pi or nor the USB Powerbank

**Zendure** USB-C Power Bank:

[image: Zendure Pic]

**Reka** USB-C Power Bank:

[image: Reka Pic]

### Test 1: Measure power connecting Pi to mains to establish baseline

5v was **LOWEST** voltage seen during monitoring period, while 1.18a was  **HIGHEST** amperage range observed.
[image: MainsPower1]

5.05v was **HIGHEST** voltage seen, while 1.15-16a tended to be **LOWEST** amperage observed.
[image: MainsPower2]

### Test 2: Compare Power Banks Connecting Pi w/ USB Cable #1

Cable used to connect each Power Bank to Pi 4: **Zendure** 21"
[image: USBcable1Zendure]

***Overall Results***: No Low Voltage warnings observed on EITHER USB -C POWER BANK despite not quite reaching 5v. Also, best voltage performance achieved using the shorter 21" Zendure USB-C cable over the 40" Reka one.

### **Power Bank #1: Zendure Tests w/ 21" Zendure Cable:**

4.78v was **LOWEST** voltage seen, while 1.18a was **HIGHEST** amperage range observed
[image: ZendureBankZendureCable1]

4.83v was **HIGHEST** voltage seen, while 1.16a was **LOWEST** amperage range observed
[image: ZendureBankZendureCable2]

### **Power Bank #2: Reka Tests w/ 21" Zendure Cable:**

4.82v was **LOWEST** voltage seen, while 1.17a was **LOWEST** amperage range observed
[image: RekaBankZendureCable1]

4.87v representative of **HIGHEST** voltage seen, while 1.31a representative of **HIGHEST** amperage range observed
[image: RekaBankZendureCable2]

### Test 3: Compare Power Banks connecting Pi w/ USB Cable #2

Cable used to connect each Power Bank to Pi 4: **Reka** 40"
[image: USBcable2Reka]

***Overall Results***: A palpable reduction in voltage from using the Reka cable which at 40" was nearly TWICE as long as the Zendure's (21"). This was enough for the Pi to throw a Low Voltage warning when connected to the Zendure Power Bank using the longer cable.  However, the Pi 4 did **NOT** show the dreaded "*Lightning bolt*" when connected to Reka Power Bank using it's own 40" USB-C cable.

### **Power Bank #1: Zendure Tests W/ 40" Reka Cable:**

4.71v was **LOWEST** voltage during monitoring period, while 1.19a was **HIGHEST** amperage range observed.
[image: ZendureBankRekaCable1]

4.73v was **HIGHEST** voltage during monitoring period, while 1.18a was **LOWEST** amperage range observed.
[image: ZendureBankRekaCable2]

**Result of Reduced Wattage**:

Using Zendure Power Bank with longer 40" Reka cable resulted in an ***Under Voltage*** warning

[image: LighteningBolt]

### **Power Bank #2: Reka Tests w/ 40" Reka Cable:**

4.77v was **LOWEST** voltage during monitoring period, while 1.19a was **LOWEST** amperage range observed.
[image: RekaBankRekaCable1]

4.81v was **HIGHEST** voltage during monitoring period, while 1.21a (*1.20a shown*)was **HIGHEST** amperage range observed.
[image: RekaBankRekaCable2]

### Test 4: Determine power overhead of dual monitors vs headless Pi 4

Finally, we'll examine power with the dual monitor cables **DISCONNECTED** using just the **ZENDURE CABLE** with each Power Bank.

Since low voltage is the problem we'll review only the HIGHEST recorded voltages observed to see how they were affected

***Overall Results***: Since we're using a battery- *a **DC** power source*- and [negative resistance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_resistance) is at play, less amperage sees increased voltage getting us closer to 5v the Pi wants. I'm not an electrical engineer, but this appears to be the relationship evidenced in my tests results shown below.

**Zendure Power Bank** powering Pi4 w/ ***Zendure*** 21" Cable:

Remark that now we can achieve 4.86 volts with the ***Zendure*** Power Bank whereas the best we managed with the HDMI monitors was 4.83v when amperage was 1.16a
[image: ZendureBankZendureCable1]

**Reka Power Bank** powering Pi4 w/ ***Zendure*** 21" Cable:

With the ***Reka*** using the Zendure cable we are now achieving 4.92v at 0.96 a whereas before with both HDMI cables connected the best we managed was 4.87v when amperage was 1.31a. Getting within touching distance of 5v now...
[image: RekaBankZendureCable1]

### Conclusion:

It very much appears that using short, thick-guage USB-C cables and a quality USB-C Power Bank you can power a Pi 4 while avoiding the "Under Voltage" warnings.  However, although I managed to get close to 5 volts with my test bench, I never fully managed to attain it.  YMMV depending on your own combination of Power Bank & USB-C cables-

Comment: Lightning and lightening mean different things.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey D'oh!  Thanks for catching that!  Just corrected it-

Answer (score 1):

To add just a minor point to F1Linux's answer...

Wrt the question:

> Can a USB-C Power Bank be used to power a Pi 4...?

Yet another caveat to the answer is that you must use a `NON e-marked` USB-C cable.

If you're interested in some [details, see this answer.](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/105819/83790) Also note the requirement to use a `NON e-marked` USB-C cable is due to a design flaw in the RPi 4, and therefore not limited to Apple-manufactured USB-C power supplies. A `NON e-marked` USB-C cable is required for **any** USB-C-compliant power supply.nothing to do in particular with an Apple-manufactured power supply.

Comment: I believe the Rpi4 has had a [board revision](https://hackaday.com/2020/02/23/raspberry-pi-slips-out-new-pcb-version-with-usb-c-power-fix/) (Feb 2020) which removes the USB-C cable problem, but I don't know when a buyer can be confident of getting the new version. They've been making them since October 2019.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: Thanks for that, I hadn't heard. Makes me wonder though - why don't they (the [Raspberry Pi Organization](https://github.com/seamusdemora/PiFormulae/blob/master/NotesCommentsThoughtsReRPiFoundation.md)) replace the defective units for free? Charity?... oh, right.

Comment: The first version is not 'defective' if you use the right power supply. I have had one since August 2019 and it works just fine. If it doesn't, buy a g--d--n lead. And yes, it's a charity.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: If you say so... but the "Head Pi Guy" says it's a design defect, and has copped to the bodge: This has been reported in several sources, including [this post on TechRepublic](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/your-new-raspberry-pi-4-wont-power-on-usb-c-cable-problem-now-officially-confirmed/), and further analyzed in [this post by Tyler Ward](https://www.scorpia.co.uk/2019/06/28/pi4-not-working-with-some-chargers-or-why-you-need-two-cc-resistors/).

Comment: The USB-C issue is a non-issue. Almost everybody uses the official power supply.

Comment: Consider the pi4 and its power supply as a unit - they work. There are too many people expecting to run a Pi with any old 'charger' they have lying around. I have always bought an official PSU with my Pis (1,2,3 and 4 so far).

Comment: @seamus Looks like the issue has finally been resolved : https://www.theregister.co.uk/2020/02/21/pi_4_fixed/

Comment: @F1Linux: Perhaps for those that buy the revised hardware. Unfortunately, I did not.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: Re "Almost everybody uses the official power supply." Maybe... but [that doesn't always work out either.](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/109246/rpi-4b-official-power-source-not-powering-it-on)