# usb-c Port of RasPi 4 used for anything else but Power?

Tags: raspi-config, usb-c

Can the usb-c Port of RasPi 4 used for anything else but Power ?

Comment: in a word - no.

Comment: I believe it can be used for USB OTG - like the Pi Zero etc - although why you would want to do this eludes me.

Answer (score 2):

YES! The USB-C port can be used as a USB  On-The-Go (OTG) port, both power and data is populated in the connector, see schematic.

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/schematics/rpi_SCH_4b_4p0_reduced.pdf

> The OTG hardware present on previous models of Pi is still available
>   and it has moved to a single connection on the USB-C port. The OTG
>   hardware is intended to be used in device-only mode on Pi 4.

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/usb/README.md

Comment: Given that the [RPi 4b can only be powered with a  `NON e-marked` USB-C cable](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/105819/83790) I'm surprised! I guess that must mean they are making `NON e-marked` USB-C cables that also support USB OTG??