# Is there a way to use the USB-C port as power and for something else?

Tags: power, data-transfer, usb-c

What I mean by something else I mean connecting my external ssd (uses usb-c) to my pi rather than the usb ports as those are slower. I have read on [usb-c Port of RasPi 4 used for anything else but Power?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/108658/usb-c-port-of-raspi-4-used-for-anything-else-but-power) that power and data is populated in the port, but I was wondering. Can you use something like a USB hub or apple's multiple-connector-into USB-c? (beacause the apple one allows a usb-c power)

Comment: the pi4 has 2xUSB3.0 ports ... and I use them for SSD at 5Gbps (max rate for USB 3.0)

Comment: Yes but that gives 640 mbps whereas my ssd goes up to 1050

Comment: SSD on a USB3.0 port should go to 5 gigabits per second ... if you're only getting 640 megabits per second, and the device is only capable of about 1 gigabit per second, then the USB-C connector won't help anyway - get a better USB3.0->SATA connector

Comment: 640 megaBYTES per second

Comment: Oh, well that is the maximum then

Comment: The USB-C on a RPI4 is purely for power and not data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The USB-C connector on the Pi **DOES NOT** implement USB-C.
It is used for power and a USB-2 OTG interface.