# Power Raspberry Pi 4 with a phone charger

Tags: pi-4, power-supply, usb-power

I've got a phone charger that delivers 4.5 A at 5 V (Huawei SuperCharge), which should be enough to power the the Pi 4. Can I use this charger or do I have to buy the original one?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Certainly looks like it supplies enough current, but the other thing to look at/check is that the voltage is stable enought. Some supplies may vary between 4.8 and 5.5 volts depending on how much of a load you are using, others might go between 4.3 and 6.5. I am just throwing some numbers out there, but these type of variations dont usually effect a phone very much, but can effect the pi.

Answer (score 4):

Yes - it will work.

### UNLESS:

The only thing you should be aware of is the possibility that your Huawei charger uses an `e-Marked` cable. The `e-Marked` cable will be a problem **IFF** you have one of the "first-run" RPi 4s, this because the Raspberry Pi Organization built thousands of units with a design flaw. The design flaw has now been recognized & corrected, but again, there are thousands of faulty ones in circulation. Some details explaining [*why** `e-Marked` cables won't work (& other details) are in this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/105819/83790).

Answer (score 2):

A minimum supply of %V 2.5A will work. So you can use that charger/adapter. But use your equipment carefully. If anything pulls current more than it needs the system will fry.

Comment: If that particular charger uses a cable that is `non e-Marked`, then it will work. Otherwise, it will not work on the "first version" of the RPI4.

Answer (score 0):

I don't personally have experience with the new Raspberry Pi but I have successfully powered all kind of Pis with all kind of power supplies and chargers. Occasionally some of the cheap chargers gave up and died but it did not happen very often.
Your phone charger is well above the recommended rating of 3A for Pi 4 so it should work without a problem.
If you want to be extra sure buy the original one.