# Can I use an Apple USB-C power supply on a RPi4?

Tags: pi-4, power, usb-c

As I was upgrading RPi3's in the field, I was surprised to find RPi4 has a new connector (USB-C) for power...

I could not find any documentation on RPi4's power supply specs, other than admission of a major error in manufacturing for the USB-C connection.

Bottom line, I cannot be sure if I use an APPLE USB-C, which loads **very high voltages**, will not burn out my RPi4 !!!

Has anyone tried using the **APPLE USB-C charger on a RPi4** ?

Answer (score 4):

Yes - you can use an Apple USB-C supply to power your RPi4, *but you will need to pay attention to **one detail** that I'll cover below*. You need not worry about damaging your RPi from the higher voltages. These higher voltages are part of the specification for USB-C that all manufacturers are *supposed* to meet. The ["major error in manufacturing"](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/your-new-raspberry-pi-4-wont-power-on-usb-c-cable-problem-now-officially-confirmed/) that you heard of is a fact, but this was due to a failure by the Raspberry Pi design team - it had nothing to do with Apple.

### The "One Detail":

With respect to the one detail I mentioned above, here's what you need to know:

1. If you have one of the early RPi4 units affected by the design flaw, you must use a [`NON e-marked`](https://www.elinfor.com/market/how-to-identify-the-usb-c-cables-with-or-without-e-maker-m-27) USB-C cable. Here is a [verified list of `NON e-marked` USB-C cables](https://www.tomshardware.com/news/raspberry-pi-4-usb-c-cables-that-work,39869.html) that you may find useful if you have one of the early, non-compliant RPi4 units. Here's one way to check if your RPi4 is one of the early (non-compliant) units:

   ```
   $ cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep Revision
   ```

   If the result is `Revision : b03111`, it's an ORIGINAL RPi4 with the USB-C design flaw.
2. If you have one of the later RPI4 units, know that The Raspberry Pi Organization has since [corrected their faulty USB-C design](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2020/02/21/pi_4_fixed/), and you may safely use any compliant USB-C cable with it.

If you're interested in further details, there are other Q&A here on RPi SE relevant to your question - [here's one.](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/105819/83790)

### Other Potential Power Issues:

Your question suggests you maintain several RPis, so I'll add this:

Since the defective RPi4 design was corrected, it seems the most common issue is with **low voltage** delivered to the RPi4's USB-C connector. This is due to two factors:

1. RPi4 requires more power than previous RPis due to performance enhancements.
2. Physics: more power `-->` more current `-->` more voltage drop in cabling.

For the RPi4, the only solutions are "better" (higher quality) cables with larger gage wiring to carry the 5V power, and/or shorter cables. Extrapolating to future generations of RPi, it seems likely that input voltage may be increased from its present 5VDC to 20VDC - currently the upper limit of the USB-C specification.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used an Apple supply but no USB-C supply will provide a high voltage without appropriate signalling from the client.

Whether the supply will work depends on the cables, but this should not be a problem with current Pi.