# Can I use a 3A/5V phone charge for powering my pi 4?

Tags: power-supply, usb-power

I have a completely fine and working type C charger with a stable voltage supply. The concern that I have is that my pi 4 is going to run 24/7 performing web scraping and analysis. Surely I have a backup system in case of a power failure, but who wants to deal with such hassles? So, my question is, if I use a phone charger to run the pi 24/7 (ample cooling) on a probable high cpu load, is there possibility of my charger dying while it's up?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I use an Apple USB-C power supply on a RPi4?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/116155/can-i-use-an-apple-usb-c-power-supply-on-a-rpi4)

Comment: depends on the specs of the charger... some shoddy manufacturers like to state a peak rather than continuous operating amperage, although that's been more my exp with cheap stuff marked "power supply" rather than "phone charger"

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, a phone charger is no more and no less reliable than the "Official Raspberry Pi Power Supply". This is self-evident from the fact that there are no published failure rates or MTBF (mean time between failure) specifications on the "Official Raspberry Pi Power Supply", just as these figures are not published for the vast majority of phone chargers for all manufacturers.

The only issue you need concern yourself with is whether or not your RPi 4 was manufactured with the design flaw that rendered the RPi 4 unable to meet the USB specifications. The impact of this design flaw is that you will need to ensure you use a `non-eMarked` cable if your RPi 4 is affected. [The details are discussed here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/116160/83790).

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  However you need to ask the manufacturer of the phone charger for its failure rates.  It might well be commercially confidential.